# Speed up search and insert to the concurrentbag c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, list, concurrency

I have a problem with slow "building" a list and I don't have idea how to speed it up.
Here is my code:

```
    private static ConcurrentBag<Classe<PojedynczeSlowa>> categoryClasses = new ConcurrentBag<Classe<PojedynczeSlowa>>();
    private const int howManyStudents = 20;
    private static int howManyClasses;
    private static EventWaitHandle[] ewhClass;
    private static List<Classe<Words>> deserializeClasses; 
//...
    public static void CreateCategoryClasses()
    {
        deserializeClasses  = Deserialize();
        howManyClasses = deserializeClasses.Count;
        ewhClass = new EventWaitHandle[howManyClasses];
        for (var i = 4; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            categoryClasses.Add(new Classe<PojedynczeSlowa>(((Categories) i).ToString()));
        }
        WaitCallback threadMethod = ParseCategories;
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(howManyStudents, howManyClasses);

        for (var i = 0; i < howManyClasses; ++i)
        {
            ewhClass[i] = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(threadMethod, i);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < howManyClasses; ++i)
        {
            ewhClass[i].WaitOne();
        }

        var xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Classe<PojedynczeSlowa>>)); //poprawić!!
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"categoryClasses.xml"))
        {
            xmls.Serialize(sw, categoryClasses.ToList());
        }
    }

    private static void ParseCategories(object index)
    {
        int sum;
        var i = index as int?;

        if (deserializeClasses[i.Value].Category == Categories.PEOPLE.ToString())
        {
            foreach (var word in deserializeClasses[i.Value].Bag)
            {
                sum =
                    deserializeClasses.Count(
                        clas =>
                            clas.Bag.Where(x => clas.Category == deserializeClasses[i.Value].Category)
                                .Contains(word));
                if (!categoryClasses.ElementAt(0).Bag.Contains(new PojedynczeSlowa(word.Word, sum)))
                {
                    categoryClasses.ElementAt(0)
                        .Bag.Add(new PojedynczeSlowa(word.Word,
                            Convert.ToDouble(sum)/
                            Convert.ToDouble(deserializeClasses.Count(x => x.Category == deserializeClasses[i.Value].Category))));
                }
            }
        }
//rest of the code which adds elements to the list on other indexes.
        ewhClass[(i).Value].Set();
    }
```

I might add that:

deserializeClasses contains about 18550 elements of class "Word",

and any of this elements ("Word") contains a list of string and int, average size of this list is about 200-250 elements. I use .net 4.5.1
Thanks for help!

Comment: Step one of performance tuning is always the same - *profile*.  Get a profiler like dotTRACE and use it.  This will show you your bottlenecks - then you can start to think about how to speed them up.  http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Comment: You're not showing `threadMethod`, which is where I assume the `categoryClasses` bag is being filled? Anyway, your `ParseCategories` algorithm has horrible runtime complexity :-) For each word in the bag, you iterate over every item in `deserializeClasses` (with `Count`), and for each of those items you iterate over every word in a bag (with `Where`). Looking like O(N^3).

Comment: You also don't mention which framework you are using.  If 4.0, see : http://ayende.com/blog/156097/the-high-cost-of-concurrentbag-in-net-4-0

Comment: @Cameron yes I know it, but i don't have any other idea how to get faster number, which is specifed by number of occurrences of the word in a bags of Word, which are included in "deserializeClasses"

Comment: @J... thanks for showing this program, the problem is that algorith of counting the number which is specifed by number of occurrences of the word in a bags of Word, which are included in "deserializeClasses" is very bad and is looking more like O(n^2k^2) where n is a size of deserializeClasses and k is a size of a list which is include in one concrete element of deserializeClasses...

Answer (score 1):

A couple things (I don't have enough rep to comment so my comments are coming in here too)...

1) Class definitions would be very helpful.  For example, you have
`if (!categoryClasses.ElementAt(0).Bag.Contains(new PojedynczeSlowa(word.Word, sum)))`
which will never be true if you haven't overridden object.Equals (did you?).  Also, it's much harder to know what's going on with an incomplete sample.
2) Your code
`sum = deserializeClasses.Count(clas => clas.Bag.Where(x => clas.Category == deserializeClasses[i.Value].Category).Contains(word));`
doesn't make use of x at all.  Consider
`sum = deserializeClasses.Count(clas => clas.Category == deserializeClasses[i.Value].Category && clas.Bag.Contains(word));`
This avoids much potential enumeration and could speed up the average cost even though the worst case cost remains the same.
3) Dictionaries are your friend.  Consider making some temp dictionaries that are indexed by whatever you're checking against.  I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what you're trying to do (see comment 1) but I'm guessing you could save quite a bit of performance cost, particularly that Contains() call, with using a Dictionary.
4) I'm not sure that multithreading is going to save you anything here.  I'm guessing it will make things slower since this looks to be CPU bound and you are adding CPU overhead with thread switching.

I would help out with some code but I'm in a bit of a hurry and don't have time to guess at the rest of the missing code to get everything to compile.

Comment: 1. I override Equals.
2. Yes I also see that and already fix.
3. Yes, I modify my code, and at first I add words to ConcurrentDic without any specific "number", and then when I have dictionary with words which i need, I run the "algorith" but it's still too slow.
Anyway thanks! I will continue to improve that, and post later what I got.